# How do I make a button that appears when another function occurs?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make a close button that appears with content and leaves when it's clicked? I have this code already but I can't seem to figure out how to make it functional.

Basically this new button that I am creating will close out the youtube video and restore the regular site back to its default.

```js
function play1() {
  var frame = document.getElementById("youtube-frame");
  frame.innerHTML += "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/AkFs3YzxN_E' frameborder='0' allow='accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
  document.getElementById('go-button').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('title').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('close').style.display = "block";
}

function close() {
  document.getElementById('youtube-frame').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('close').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('title').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('go-button').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-animate-opacity w3-text-white">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hidden-button w3-display-topright" style="display: none" onclick="close()">×</a>
  <div class="w3-display-middle">
    <div id="title">
      <h1 class="w3-jumbo w3-animate-top">TAKE YOUR MARK</h1>
      <hr class="w3-border-grey" style="margin:auto;width:40%">
    </div>
    <div id="go-button">
      <p><button class="w3-center center transparent_btn" onclick="play1()">go</button></p>
    </div>
    <div id="youtube-frame" class="w3-display-middle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `close` **id** to the element where you are actually calling `function close() {...}`. So, in the `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hidden-button w3-display-topright" style = "display: none" onclick="close()">×</a>` add an ID, making it look like

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close" class="hidden-button w3-display-topright" style = "display: none" onclick="close()">×</a>`

You're basically not targeting the `X` - close - element anywhere in your javascript, since the element does not have a `id="close"`, and you're trying to get it with `document.getElementById("close")`.

Comment: That helped make it appear, thanks! But I'm still having trouble getting that x button to close the youtube frame and make that text/go button reappear.

Comment: Try `console.log("test")` in the  `function close()`  to see if the function is getting called in the first place, even though it should be, since you have `onclick="close()"` on the X element.

Comment: What is that supposed to do? I'm currently looking at a live preview and still noting is happening

Comment: You need to utilize the developer tools & console a little bit more. It should log "test" in the console if the function is actually being called when the X is pressed, if not, it will throw an error and we'll see what needs to be done.

Comment: This is what I got back: invalid/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Share the code on hastebin.com and send it here so I could take a look :)

Comment: I noticed that and figured it out. I had to create the iframe up in the youtube div and set it to no display. Then in my function I just had it make the frame in block display. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help :)